# Superior Form - VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, topmost

I'm doing a two-form Visual Studio project .
I have seen particular forms in many applications:
If you click the area out of this forms, you can hear the windows "DLIN" sound , and you can't select the other forms under it . 
**( I don't mean The "TopMost" characteristic of a form , but something like )** 
Does someone know the name of this form type or a feature that i have to set to the form in my project ?

Comment: It's known as a modal dialogue.

Comment: Yes, I knew modal dialogues, but I didn't know that they could be applied in a form .

Comment: They can ONLY be applied "in a form". What do you think a dialogue box is? It's a form.

Comment: sorry , i confused modal dialogs with file dialogs and something like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you show a form using [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ShowDialog), it will block access to other forms as long as it's active, and on default sound scheme, you will hear a sound on attempting to interact with other form.